# SQL: remove all special char's from Timestamp field and convert as INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ID column coming from different source systems. This ID is sometimes NULL and the downstream requirement is NOT to have any null's on the reports. Hence business has decided to use the Timestamp field(Created Date) to replace NULL's in the ID column.

So when ID is NULL, I wanted to convert my CreatedDate as ID(to INT) so it would be unique for any NULL record.

Example:If `ID = NULL` and `CreatedDate = 2015-12-09 23:12:44.947`
then `ID = 09122015231244(DDMMYYYYHHMMSS)`

Currently, my code is as below which is not yielding expected results:

```
Convert (nvarchar(50),(Convert(BIGINT,(DATEPART(day,CreatedOn)*1000000 
+ DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedOn)*10000 + DATEPART(Year,(CreatedOn)) )) *10000
+DATEPART(HOUR,CreatedON)*100 +DATEPART(minute,CreatedOn)
+ DATEPART(second,CreatedOn)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: provide some sample data and expected result please

Comment: Sorry but `9122015231244` would overflow an int column (ints support -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647 - [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)).  You could use a bigint, but you'll still lose the leading zero.  Are you using time, down to the second, in an attempt to generate a unique number?  Do duplicates matter?

Comment: Hi, I tried using BIGINT, but still losing leading zero. I need to use the field till seconds in DDMMYYYYHHMMSS format.

Comment: @user7617078 you cant have leading zeros in datatype int or bigint, u can use varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make use of below query:

```
    DECLARE @dt DATETIME ='2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'

    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @dt, 103),'/','')+
           RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(hour, @dt) as varchar(2)),2)+
           RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(minute, @dt)as varchar(2)),2)+
           RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(Second, @dt)as varchar(2)),2)
```

OUTPUT

```
09122015231244
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below example:

```
DECLARE @Date AS DateTime='2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'

SELECT CASE LEN(CAST(Day(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2))) WHEN 1 THEN '0'+CAST(Day(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) ELSE CAST(Day(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) END 
    + CASE LEN(CAST(Month(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2))) WHEN 1 THEN '0'+CAST(Day(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) ELSE CAST(Month(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) END
    + CAST(Year(@Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    + CAST(DATEPART(Hour,(@Date)) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
    + CAST(DATEPART(Minute,(@Date)) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
    + CAST(DATEPART(Second,(@Date)) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @D datetime = '2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'

SELECT  (CAST(DATEPART(DAY, @D) as bigint) * 1000000000) + 
        (CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @D) as bigint) * 10000000) + 
        (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @D) as bigint) * 100000) + 
        (CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @D) as bigint) * 1000) + 
        (CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @D) as bigint) * 10) + 
        CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @D) as bigint)
```

Result:

```
    9321523164
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/YGIB37867)

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a solution with the SQL-Server doc :

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/

I think the following code solves your problem :

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME ='2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), @date, 105),'-','')+
RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(hour, @date) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+
RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(minute, @date) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+
RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(Second, @date) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
12092015231244
```

But i see that type int is to small to store the new ID. You should use :

- Use a bigint
- Shorten your id.

*I'm sorry for my English, because is not my native language.*

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to convert DATETIME to INT

```
 DECLARE @dt DATETIME 
 SELECT @dt = '2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'
 SELECT CONVERT(INT, @dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work. `+` operator will work different with Int and Varchar datatype.

If value is of type numeric type it will do addition. And if it is applied on Varchar value then it will just concatenate. `Datepart` will give you Integer output and `Datename` will give you varchar output.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME ='2015-12-09 23:12:44.947'

SELECT @DATE , DATENAME(D,@DATE)
             +CAST(DATEPART(MM,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(50))
             +DATENAME(YY,@DATE)
             +DATENAME(HH,@DATE)
             +DATENAME(MINUTE,@DATE)
             +DATENAME(SS,@DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
declare @e varchar(50)
set @e = '123.54'
select cast(replace(@e,'.','') as int)
```

You can repeat replace until all characters is gone then cast as int.

Answer (score 0):

convert char '103' gives you ddmmyyyy, replace '/' with empty string and append the time(114) by replacing ':' with empty string and voila, you get what you need

```
Declare @dt datetime = getdate(),@string varchar(max)
select @string = replace(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt, 103), '/', '')+convert(varchar(8),@dt, 114), ':','')
```

output:10042017151704

which is exactly DDMMYYYYHHMMSS as u need

but it can't be int,u can cast it as bigint though,

thus

```
 declare @a bigint = cast(@string as bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <your_table_name> SET <yourcolumn_name>=concat('+1',<yourcolumn_name>);
```